# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state_claim_ratio_df' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def cal_monthly_avg(monthly_df, st_pop_data, current_year):

    st_pop_data.set_index('State', inplace=True)
    # Final us population by adding all population in state
    us_pop = st_pop_data['Population'].sum()
    # add state population into monthly_df
    monthly_cols = monthly_df.columns
    temp_df = pd.merge(monthly_df, st_pop_data, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    for col in monthly_cols:
        sum_monthly_claim = temp_df[col].sum()
        # print(sum_monthly_claim)
        us_per_100k_people_claims = sum_monthly_claim * 100000 / us_pop
        # print(us_per_100k_people_claims)
        temp_df[col] = temp_df[col] * 100000 / temp_df['Population'] / us_per_100k_people_claims

    # drop column Population
    temp_df.drop('Population', axis=1, inplace=True)
    full_quarter_list = [parameters.update_year + 'Q1', parameters.update_year + 'Q2', parameters.update_year + 'Q3', parameters.update_year + 'Q4']
    max_month = max(monthly_cols)

    if int(parameters.update_year) < current_year:
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q1'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[0:3]].mean(axis=1)
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q2'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[3:6]].mean(axis=1)
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q3'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[6:9]].mean(axis=1)
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q4'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[9:12]].mean(axis=1)
        state_claim_ratio_df = temp_df[full_quarter_list]

    elif max_month < 12 & max_month >= 9:
        part_quarter_list = [parameters.update_year + 'Q1', parameters.update_year + 'Q2', parameters.update_year + 'Q3']
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q1'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[0:3]].mean(axis=1)
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q2'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[3:6]].mean(axis=1)
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q3'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[6:9]].mean(axis=1)
        state_claim_ratio_df = temp_df[part_quarter_list]

    elif max_month < 9 & max_month >= 6:
        part_quarter_list = [parameters.update_year + 'Q1', parameters.update_year + 'Q2']
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q1'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[0:3]].mean(axis=1)
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q2'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[3:6]].mean(axis=1)
        state_claim_ratio_df = temp_df[part_quarter_list]

    elif max_month < 6 & max_month >= 3:
        part_quarter_list = [parameters.update_year + 'Q1']
        temp_df[parameters.update_year + 'Q1'] = temp_df[temp_df.columns[0:3]].mean(axis=1)
        state_claim_ratio_df = temp_df[part_quarter_list]

    return state_claim_ratio_df
```

this function is save in function.py, then I import this function into another script 
`cal_weekly_claims.py.`

then use this function in cal_weekly_claims.py:

`df = function.cal_monthly_avg(monthly_df, st_pop_data, '2018')`

I got an error.

error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state_claim_ratio_df' referenced before assignment

Why I get this error?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to define `state_claim_ratio_df` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

None of your conditions are true, so the variable is not defined.

This is because you are not using the right operator. In Python, boolean "and" is `and`. The `&` operator is for bitwise comparison.

```
elif max_month < 12 and max_month >= 9:
```

etc.

Note though that your conditions are more idiomatically expressed with chained comparisons anyway:

```
if 9 <= max_month < 12:
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.